# how do i delete .blendcache files from desktop?

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation

I seemed to have deleted the files associated with the '.blendcache' files that can't be deleted or moved.
Any ideas are welcome.

After some checking, I think the files are generated by using the fluid modifier.
Moving the '.blend' file without also moving the '.blendcache',
is the problem.
Once separated, the '.blendcache' is stuck.

Is it a Blender issue or a Windows thing?

thanks for any thoughts and ideas

Comment: Do you have blender open? The cache is generated when you have the file open

Comment: Can you delete other files from your desktop (i.e. it's not protected)?